# Detect grid in 2D plane

Tags: dataset, measurement-error, back-transformation

Given is a set of points (x,y) in a two dimensional Cartesian coordinate system. Many points are near the crossing points of an affine transformed grid. The points have been measured and may have:

1. position errors (approx. less than 10%) of the grid spacing
2. some points are missing
3. some grid crossings are occupied twice or even more often
4. a few points may be completely wrong (random)

The goal is to identify base vectors of the transformed grid and thus to identify the affine transformation as robust as possible.

[image]

Idea: Perfect in my book would be something like the Hough transform for grids. But one would need at least 6 parameters and thus a 6 dimensional space.

First approach was to classify the distance to the nearest neighbour. The multiple occupied crossings do results in much smaller values and the missing points do result in bigger values. The affine transformation results in different distances along the x- and y-axis. That is all making the classification error-prone.

Second approach was to 2D classify the distance and direction to the nearest neighbour to distinguish better between x- and y-axis distances.

Are there any more advanced methods to identify the grid?

Comment: Thanks. I hope that this is the suitable site for this kind of problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem, have you ever found a solution ?